# How to embed content on google site perfectly sized so that the content is not scrollable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-sites

I had been helping my local toastmasters division out with the division's website and had been adding some content by embedding code in the site's webpage. As someone with little prior knowledge of web programming and design, the embedding in google sites had been driving me crazy.

If I embed it perfectly with little amount of white space, as shown on [this page](https://www.sgdivisionv.org/clubs/v2/hb/setvote), the desktop version will show up with a lot of white space, but still bearable, but the mobile version will have a scroll bar and the scroll bar will make the page's scrolling feel very uncomfortable as it is a scroll bar within a scrollable page.

If I embed it with EXTREME amount of white space, as shown on [this page](https://www.sgdivisionv.org/clubs/v2/hb/vote). (You might need to disable ad blocker to view properly as I am checking ip to prevent multiple submissions in a row) This time android chrome and firefox work perfectly with no scrollbar and the page's scrolling feel good. The desktop version naturally have an extreme amount of white space, undesirable, but iOS safari still have some annoying scrolling despite the scroll bar not appearing.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7Zd6.jpg) showing the 2 pages on google site design view and on mobile.

How can I embed content on google sites so that they are perfectly sized and scrolls naturally, preferably without the huge amount of white space? I tried to look up similar problems but they seems to be for iframes, which I am not using here.

Answer (score 0):

Write something like this (for embedded code):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <!--Do something here-->
    <script>
      parent.document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].scrolling = "no";
      // Do more stuff here;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But this *might* lead to some of the content being chopped off at the bottom so you need to expand the frame until all the content is visible.